# windows could not start the service.ERROR 2

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2

I am working on a windows server 2008 R2 .I have created some services for my VB6 application in server.But when i am trying to start the service, an error popup is coming saying windows could not start the service .Error 2:system cannot find the file specified. I checked that file location is correct and i tried to give administrator and system as full access to the folders where these files are located.

Comment: Does this service also use an installer--sometimes the server may need rebooted depending on how it installs, ect. before services will start for some apps? Does it write registry keys with the full path plus the exe file name? Double check that logic if so.  Also, double check that the full path plus file name is not more than 256 characters in length starting from the drive letter, all the way to the file name extension counting colons, backslashes, spaces, and all.... for example... `C:\folder\folder 2\filename.ext`. being a count of `31`.